# write rowcount int variable to txt file

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that loads flat files into several SQL tables. I would like to count the rows from the flat file and spit it out to a log file (.txt).

I added the rowcount step in data flow and it places the count to a INT variable. How can I pass the count in the variable to a .txt file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rowcount` transform is really supposed to be used so you can access the rowcount outside of the Data Flow Task. What you want is the `Aggregate` transform. When you configure it, you'll set up a `Count all` aggregation, similar to this:

[image]

Then you just pipe the output of the aggregate to your Flat File Destination. If you want to perform your other Data Flow operations in the same DFT, you could add a `Multicast` transform after your source. Your DFT might look something like this simplified screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I have been using rowcount to variable and reading it into the dataflow with a script task. I'd kind of still use that approach for many rowcounts (i.e. starting count, after a split, etc all getting logged onto one row